# I get a "Session description is NULL" error when trying to set remote description after getting the sdp from the server

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I'm trying to write an android application that displays a stream I get from d-id service: https://docs.d-id.com/reference/get-started. This should take an image and a text as input and stream back a video of this image moving libs while saying the input text.

It uses WebRTC for the streaming and I'm trying to implement it but I'm stuck at trying to send an answer after the initial offer.

Here's the function where I do that. Sorry for the wall of code, I'm in the heavy testing phase:

I get the "Session description is NULL" error on the onSetFailure(String s) callback of the setRemoteDescription call

```
post("https://api.d-id.com/talks/streams", json, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.e("OKHTTP FAILURE: ", e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String responseStr = response.body().string();
                    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(responseStr).getAsJsonObject();
                    streamID = jsonObject.get("id").getAsString();
                    session_id = jsonObject.get("session_id").getAsString();

                    String stunUrl = jsonObject.get("iceServers").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("urls").getAsString();
                    String turnUrl = jsonObject.get("iceServers").getAsJsonArray().get(1).getAsJsonObject().get("urls").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsString();
                    String username = jsonObject.get("iceServers").getAsJsonArray().get(1).getAsJsonObject().get("username").getAsString();
                    String credential = jsonObject.get("iceServers").getAsJsonArray().get(1).getAsJsonObject().get("credential").getAsString();
                    String sdp = jsonObject.get("offer").getAsJsonObject().get("sdp").getAsString();

                    List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new ArrayList<>();
                    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer(stunUrl));
                    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer(turnUrl, username, credential));

                    // Create peer connection
                    PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(activity, true, true, true);
                    PeerConnectionFactory factory = new PeerConnectionFactory(null);
                    PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers);
                    peerConnection = factory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, new MediaConstraints(), pcObserver);
                    SessionDescription sessionDesc = new SessionDescription(OFFER, sdp);
                    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
                            super.onCreateSuccess(sessionDescription);
                            peerConnection.createAnswer(new SimpleSdpObserver() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
                                    peerConnection.setLocalDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
                                    String json = "{\"answer\":{\"type\":\"answer\",\"sdp\":\""+sessionDescription.description+"\"},\"session_id\":\""+session_id+"\"}";
                                    post("https://api.d-id.com/talks/streams/"+streamID+"/sdp", json, new Callback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                                            Log.e("ANSWER FAILURE: ", e.toString());
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                                            String responseStr = response.body().string();
                                            Log.e("ANSWER SUCCESS: ", responseStr);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCreateFailure(String s) {
                                    super.onCreateFailure(s);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onSetSuccess() {
                                    super.onSetSuccess();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onSetFailure(String s) {
                                    super.onSetFailure(s);
                                }
                            }, new MediaConstraints());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCreateFailure(String s) {
                            super.onCreateFailure(s);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSetSuccess() {
                            super.onSetSuccess();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSetFailure(String s) {
                            super.onSetFailure(s);
                        }
                    }, sessionDesc);

                    Log.e("OKHTTP SUCCESS: ", responseStr);
                } else {
                    Log.e("OKHTTP UNSUCCESS: ", "");
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is the sdp string I receive from the server.

```
v=0
o=- 1680708165776536 1 IN IP4 35.164.244.161
s=Mountpoint 7117298691349140
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE a v d
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 F8:F6:8D:3D:A4:B0:9C:7A:A4:4C:6C:11:5B:59:D4:7B:2C:02:55:87:31:84:87:C1:83:B4:5E:A2:F7:4C:A5:1A
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS *
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111
c=IN IP4 35.164.244.161
a=sendonly
a=mid:a
a=rtcp-mux
a=ice-ufrag:ol8o
a=ice-pwd:QwtILzHdCR7CEZO8T5BpmV
a=ice-options:trickle
a=setup:actpass
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=msid:janus janusa
a=ssrc:575475372 cname:janus
a=candidate:1 1 udp 2015363327 35.164.244.161 41669 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 udp 1679819007 35.164.244.161 41669 typ srflx raddr 172.18.0.4 rport 41669
a=end-of-candidates
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100 101
c=IN IP4 35.164.244.161
a=sendonly
a=mid:v
a=rtcp-mux
a=ice-ufrag:ol8o
a=ice-pwd:QwtILzHdCR7CEZO8T5BpmV
a=ice-options:trickle
a=setup:actpass
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=ssrc-group:FID 1591203620 1663244846
a=msid:janus janusv
a=ssrc:1591203620 cname:janus
a=ssrc:1663244846 cname:janus
a=candidate:1 1 udp 2015363327 35.164.244.161 41669 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 udp 1679819007 35.164.244.161 41669 typ srflx raddr 172.18.0.4 rport 41669
a=end-of-candidates
m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP4 35.164.244.161
a=sendrecv
a=mid:d
a=sctp-port:5000
a=ice-ufrag:ol8o
a=ice-pwd:QwtILzHdCR7CEZO8T5BpmV
a=ice-options:trickle
a=setup:actpass
a=candidate:1 1 udp 2015363327 35.164.244.161 41669 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 udp 1679819007 35.164.244.161 41669 typ srflx raddr 172.18.0.4 rport 41669
a=end-of-candidates
```

Hopefully you can help me understand the problem.
Cheers,
Samuel

I tried to create the session description as a stringified JSON, changed the order I did all those things, and lots of other futile tentatives.
I also tried using sdpoker tool to check for sdp problems but I don't understand the output.

Here it is:

```
Found 11 error(s) in SDP file:
1: Stream 1: Each stream description shall have a media-level 'mediaclk' attribute, as per SMPTE ST 2110-10 Section 8.1.
2: Stream 2: Each stream description shall have a media-level 'mediaclk' attribute, as per SMPTE ST 2110-10 Section 8.1.
3: Stream 3: Each stream description shall have a media-level 'mediaclk' attribute, as per SMPTE ST 2110-10 Section 8.1.
4: Stream 1: Stream descriptions shall have a media-level 'ts-refclk' attribute, as per SMPTE ST 2110-10 Section 8.2.
5: Stream 2: Stream descriptions shall have a media-level 'ts-refclk' attribute, as per SMPTE ST 2110-10 Section 8.2.
6: Stream 3: Stream descriptions shall have a media-level 'ts-refclk' attribute, as per SMPTE ST 2110-10 Section 8.2.
7: Line 46: Separate source address grouping is not an acceptable pattern, with reference to RFC 7104.
8: Line 5: Separate destination address grouping is not an acceptable pattern, with reference to RFC 7104.
9: Got to line 10, the end of session-level description, without finding the destination group, with reference to RFC 7104.
10: Line 27: Found a media description for video with a pattern that is not acceptable.
11: Line 10: Found a media description for audio with a pattern that is not acceptable.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the local description first before setting the remote description.

Comment: To do that I need a sessionDescription to pass as parameter but I have nothing, what should I put?

Comment: If you're sending the answer use that answer as local session description. If you're sending the offer, then use that offer as local session description.

Comment: I get the same error. Maybe the sdp I get is somehow wrong?